# Is there a conditional for a possible condition in the past?

Tags: conditionals

If I look at some table of conditionals, such as one [here](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/), all past conditions are considered unreal.

But a past condition easily can be quite possible. For example, *when the speaker simply doesn't know what actions were done or how they were done and is speculating about the possible variants.*

Imagine the situation: You don't know which way was chosen by your friend, but depending on it, there could be different consequences. And you say something as:

> If she <s>did chose</s> the left way, 
>       she could have met the wolf and it is because of that she is not here yet.
>
> But if she <s>did chose</s> the right way, 
>       she could have met the woodcutter and now she is not here because of him.

Of course, both conditions here are bad, and I do not know how to write them, and the grammatical tables won't help. Really, I am not sure about the second halves, too.

I think, that it should look like the first conditional, only moved to the past, but the logic won't work here...

**Disclaimer**: Notice, it is not The Past **Real** Conditional, mentioned [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/387886/confusion-about-past-real-conditional), for

> it describes what you **used to do** in particular real-life situations.

Comment: *"If he was at the party last night, I didn't see him."* As opposed to *"If he had been at the party last night, I would have seen him."*

Comment: @PeterShor No, that is not what I am talking about, sorry, for you already had or had not seen him and know the result. So, if you suppose differently, you will use unreal cause. Maybe, with somebody else? Could you use the example with the Red Hat?

Comment: *"If he was at the party last night, I didn't see him"* is a past conditional that is real. So this contradicts your first sentence *"all past conditions are considered unreal,"* even if it wasn't exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: @PeterShor No. The past real conditional speaks about the things, that used to happen. It is an absolutely different theme.

Comment: I've changed my comment. I meant that it is a past conditional that is real, not that it is the construction that some people call the "past real conditional".

Comment: @PeterShor Sorry, in tables I see 0, 1, 2, 3 and mixed conditionals. Look at the reference from the question. No probable conditions in the past. Your example says nothing about what is and what is not in the tables. So, it does not imply the contradictory mentioned by you.

Comment: Those tables are ridiculously incomplete. My example is perfectly good English, even if it's not in the tables.

Comment: If she did choose the left way, she could have met the wolf and that  could be the explanation why she is not here yet.

Comment: You see, already two monsters of linguistics have two different ways how to say this. Or both are correct?

Comment: @PeterShor It is clear that they are not full, or I won't need to ask my question! But can I get some explanation, please? About the question of mine?

Comment: Really, I like the answer of Edwin, but my sensitivity in English is definitely not something I can base on.

Comment: @PeterShor Can you advice a full table? Or some other good book on the subject?

Comment: I had found a page on the theme: http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/condition1a.html. It seems, @PeterShor is right.

Comment: @PeterShor Could you put your thought as an answer and add a reference there? (You could use one from the previous comment)

Comment: The problem is that it's fairly complicated, and would take some time, which I don't have much of right now. I've bookmarked this page, and will try to remember to do it at some point if nobody beats me to it..

Comment: These monsters of linguistics are certainly confusing the hell out of the rest of us :)

Comment: For those who are confused by Edwin's and my answers contradicting each other, they're both correct.